# Performance counters in AD LDS

Tags: windows-server, adam, adlds

Are there any performance counters for an AD LDS instance? I have searched for them without success. I know that there are performance counters for AD DS, but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around in Windows Server 2012 R2 and found that there is an object called DirectoryServices which is available for AD LDS instances. I verified a few of the counters, for example LDAP Client Sessions.

There seems to be no documentation about this in AD LDS sections of Windows Server.